# Delete start message from selenium webdriver ie

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I m using Selenium IE Webdriver.I want to delete "This is the initial page of webdriver server." from IEDriverServer.exe file of Selenium IE Webdriver. I opened the IEDriverServer.exe file in notepad++ and deleted that line from it and again add it in my classpath.But then i get this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

How can we do that.Please someone tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just edit an executable file like that. You have undoubtedly **ruined** the executable and now should redownload it from the Selenium site.

Regardless, this is expected behaviour. The IEDriver must have *somewhere* to go to begin with.

There is a setting that configures this URL called [InitialBrowserURL](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver.html#INITIAL_BROWSER_URL). If this is not configured in your code, then the default is used.

Configure this to what you want. Most cases it can be configured to just go to the home page of your application.